# PHP - Why does || return 1 while OR returns value?

Tags: php

I am sending a POST request from my client to the server and fetch the value on the server like this:

```
$fileName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fileName", FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) or exit("No Filename");
exit($fileName);
```

**Example Output:** 'vacation_photo.jpg'

This works fine, however, if I replace `or` with `||` then I get **1** as output.

**Output:** '1'

I was reading [this article](https://gist.github.com/janogarcia/4268731) but I still don't get it.

Comment: It's about precedence http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` and `or` have a different precedence. See [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). If make it clear with parentheses you'll get:

```
fileName = (filter || exit)
(fileName = filter) OR exit
```

Then the exit in the second line prints true as 1.